# I want to Pull Submission Id from Elementor Form into a redirect url

Tags: forms, elementor

I have been trying to Pull the Submission_ID from one URl in subdomain to Another URL in Main Domain.

Eg when someone submits a form, I need it to redirect to eg [www.example.com/custom.pnp?submission_id=](http://www.example.com/custom.pnp?submission_id=) (Actual Submission Id of Form Submitted)

Anyone has any idea on same?

Tried to incorporate Field ID tag [field id="submission_id"], but it doesnt work

[www.example.com/custom.pnp?submission_id=[field](http://www.example.com/custom.pnp?submission_id=%5Bfield) id="submission_id"] not working

Comment: The link doesn't work.